# Aframe pass variables between functions in component

Tags: javascript, aframe

I’m trying to stop the throttledFunction from running unless the “fly” event listener has been emitted. But I can’t change the “this.ballhit” variable from inside the eventlistener.

I don’t know how to pass variables between functions within the component.

```
 AFRAME.registerComponent('ballflyact', {
  init: function () {
     var el = this.el;
     this.ballhit = '';
      el.addEventListener('fly', function () {
        this.ballhit = true;
      });

  },

tick: function (t, dt) {
     if (!this.ballhit) {  return; }
    this.throttledFunction();  // Called once a second.
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function, `this` becomes different.

You can use self-binding function `el.addEventListener('fly', () => { // ... });`

Or like `var self = this; el.addEventListener('fly', function () { self.ballHit = true; });`

Answer (score 0):

The following works. Thank you. Now the throttle function will only run for ~10,000 milliseconds after the “fly” event, not constantly in the background.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('ballflyact', {
  init: function () {
     var el = this.el;
     this.ballhit = '';
     var self = this;
      el.addEventListener('fly', function () {
        self.ballhit = true;
                       // more code
                       setTimeout((e)=>{
                       self.ballhit = '';
                      }, 10000)
      });
    },
tick: function (t, dt) {
     if (!this.ballhit) {  return; }
    this.throttledFunction();  // Called once a second.
    },
});
```